# Youtube Data API v3 subscribers count for channel is wrong or cached

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to use Youtube Data API (V3) for fetching subscribers count for a channel.

The endpoint is `/channels?id=CHANNEL_ID&part=statistics`,

However, I'm not getting results in realtime. 
Also, when I subscribe to a channel, no subscriber count is increased on neither youtube page and API.

I can't see any kind of information about this kind of delay or error in their API docs.

Could you help me with this please? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the solution in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723866/youtube-subscriber-count-with-youtube-data-api-v3)?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the same api endpoint and it has a problem.

Comment: facing the same issue in android app with same api  v3.